# How can the french opening be avoided?

Tags: opening, french-defense

I'm really not good at the french when I'm with white, is there a good way to avoid it and get my opponent outside of their preparation?

Comment: Have you considered using King's Indian Attack? It is very effective against the French and easy to remember...

Comment: no, and never heard of it. what does it go?

Comment: Play 1.d4 then! Or perhaps 1.Nf3, 1.c4, 1.g3, etc.

Comment: @RachidO.: Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Indian_Attack).

Comment: It is not technically avoiding the French defense, but most "French" players hate the exchange variation `1.e4 e6, 2.d4 d5, 3.exd5`, so maybe you could try that.

Comment: True, most `French` players hate exchange. But it's too drawish for white as well. So as a `e4` player you need to cope with it somehow. Against stronger opponents maybe exchange variation is promising for a draw.

Comment: If you want to be a strong e4-player, study the main lines :) Well, as for your question, do you mean play 1.e4 and avoid main lines in French or play something other than 1.e4? You should clarify your question! Even better, use the board viewer and show what you play with white today against the French!

Comment: Another way to avoid French-like positons is the Tarrasch: 1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nd2, then Black usually ends up with a queen pawn isolated.

Comment: The KIA setup against the French if e4, d3, Nd2, Ngf3, g3, Bg2.  The order can change but most play in this order to prevent a queen trade.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are trying to avoid French-like positions, rather than avoiding the named opening - the latter is latter impossible after 1.e4 as most texts consider the French beginning as soon as black plays 1.e6.

In short, if you want to play 1.e4 regularly there is no way of avoiding the French Defence with a 'standard' opening. After 1.e4 e6, all sensible moves from White can be made to resemble some features of the French if Black wants to press the game in that direction.

To give some general advice: avoiding an opening by playing really unusual moves almost always results in objectively worse positions if your opponent plays correctly. Because of this, I'd recommend putting time into finding a *response* to the French that gives you a position that you feel more comfortable with. The Exchange variation is very different from the Advance, which is different again from the Classical and Winawer. With the number of different lines you should eventually be able to find something you at least don't feel too uncomfortable playing. Alternatively, a system-like approach with the King's Indian Attack (KIA) or similar could work if you don't want to learn lines that your opponent may be more familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your style. You may go with  `2 c4` or `2 g3` would lead to very different positions

Answer (score -10):

> This is the most monotonous and annoying play you can imagine - it rarely gives rise to combinations of some interest.  -  Serafino Dubois

That's one of that really say about french opening.
As you said you're playing as white, 
I'd like to Recommend you to go for 1. d4 (in french opening it starts with 1. e4 e6)
and go for  King's Indian Defence, It's really useful and I personally won 60% Matches with it.
Otherwise if you for 1. e4 you have a less chance for French Opening, as there is High for King's Gambit [Source : My personal games]

Let's say that you get French Opening, then go for French Defense:Frankfurt Variation
that is 1.e4 e6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.Bg5 Be7 5.e5 Ng8 6.Be3 b6
It's really belived to be Advantage for white.

Anyways, It's Chess and Completely Depends upon How you play it.

Comment: woah, Black doesn't necessarily have to play this way.

Comment: Please edit your answer so that it fits the question asked. I do agree that going for `1.d4` is a correct answer, but the rest is clearly not forced and not relevant.

Comment: Lol @ downvotes